# ReactJs + Electron - Socket connection only working after reload

Tags: reactjs, sockets, electron

I'm working on a little project using react and electron, the app connects to a league of legends socket that reads data from the game using this library(https://league-connect.supergrecko.dev/docs/api).

In order to get electron and that library working inside react, I use:

```
window.ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
window.league_connect = require("league-connect");
```

And then I use window.league_connect to use it in react.
Then in a component I create a socket and start listening for an event.

```
window.league_connect.connect(this.props.lcuConnector.connection)
      .then((socket) => {
        this.socket = socket;
        console.log("conected to socket");
        this.subscribeChampSelection();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

It works, but when I open the socket it won't listen to any messages until the app reloads one time, then everythings works fine.
Another thing that fails is when I close the socket and then connect again, it does the same thing, I need to reload again to make it work.

No errors in log, the socket is created and everything looks fine but it only works if you reload the page.

There is any reason for this to happen?
Thanks for your time and sorry if I misspell some words, I'm not too good at english.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that any libraries that works only on node doesn't work very well with react. But electron does, so I made some handlers in electron that calls the function in the main process (inaccessible from react) from the renderer process (accesible from react via electron).

```
window.ipcRenderer = require("electron").ipcRenderer;
```

Then electron responds to react asynchronously or executes whatever code I need, the only problem is that you need to create a handler for every function that you need to call.

**electron.js**

```
ipc.handle("CHECK_READY_FOR_MATCH", checkReadyForMatch);
```

**React component**

```
const electron = window.electron;
electron.ipcRenderer.invoke(
            "CHECK_READY_FOR_MATCH",
            params
          );
```